# Filling a Range with data

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am working with several `Ranges` which contain data, and out of these `Ranges` I have to calculate means and other stuff. But before I can do so I need to find outliers and mark them as such. Most of it works fine but I have a problem when trying to fill the `Range` where I want to mark the outliers as outliers. I have read before that I can't fill anything but the Cell where I call the function from with values. That is why I tried a sub instead.

Please see below a simple version of what i would like to achive.

The Error I receive is that there is an issue with a datatype

```vb
Function MySheet()
    'returns a String containing the Worksheet Name
    MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
End Function

Sub FillIt(Register As String, x As Long, y As Long, Val As String)
    Debug.Print Register, x, y, Val, TypeName(Val)
    ' I checked the passed Values which have made it until here and they seem fine
    Sheets(Register).Cells(x, y) = Val ' The problem must lie here but I have almost the same in another sub and there it works.
End Sub

Function Fill(myRange As Range) ' This is what will get called from the worksheet
    Dim Register As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Register = MySheet()
    For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count
            Debug.Print i, j
            If i * j Mod 2 = 0 Then
                Call FillIt(Register, myRange.Row + i - 1, myRange.Column + j - 1, "o") ' there is an issue with this line
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Fill = 88 ' just as a return value to check if it works
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions, by definition, return a single value - they aren't allowed to affect other cells. For affecting multiple cells like this you'll need to do it in a `Sub`. I quickly adapted yours to the below for testing and it seemed to work ('work' = complete with no errors) - but you'll need some way of calling the sub obviously.

```
Sub FillIt(Register As String, x As Long, y As Long, Val As String)
    Debug.Print Register, x, y, Val, TypeName(Val)
    ' I checked the passed Values which have made it until here and they seem fine
    Sheets(Register).Cells(x, y) = Val ' The problem must lie here but I have almost the same in another sub and there it works.
End Sub

Sub Fill(myRange As Range) ' This is what will get called from the worksheet
    Dim Register As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Register = ActiveSheet.Name
    For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count
            Debug.Print i, j
            If i * j Mod 2 = 0 Then
                Call FillIt(Register, myRange.Row + i - 1, myRange.Column + j - 1, "o") ' there is an issue with this line
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub Testing()
Call Fill(ActiveSheet.Range("C10:E15"))
End Sub
```

If you'll be wanting to do this on various different ranges I suggest putting in an `Application.Inputbox` at the start of the sub to set your Range variable.

Comment: So my only problem is that Fill as a `Function` instead of being a `Sub` ?

Comment: @LostInTheJungle That's what was causing the error, yep. You tried my above code at all, does it work as you expect? (it's the `Testing()` sub you run to call it)

Comment: Yes it works but I want to be able to call it from the worksheet as a function.. but that just means I need to write another function to determine outliers which i can then call on the cell where the marking of being an outlier or not goes, would have been fancier to be able to fill the range but works the other way round as well..